# C# Chat - Client is connecting even if server doesn't accept

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

I made a simple chat in C# (Console application),

this is my Server:

```
static readonly object _lock = new object();
    static readonly Dictionary<int, TcpClient> list_clients = new Dictionary<int, TcpClient>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int count = 1;
        TcpListener ServerSocket = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 5000);
        ServerSocket.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient client = ServerSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
            lock (_lock) list_clients.Add(count, client);
            Console.WriteLine("Client connected");
            Thread t = new Thread(handle_clients);
            t.Start(count);
            count++;
        }
    }

    public static void handle_clients(object o)
    {
        int id = (int)o;
        TcpClient client;

        lock (_lock) client = list_clients[id];

        while (true)
        {
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int byte_count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            if (byte_count == 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            string data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, byte_count);
            Console.WriteLine(data);
        }

        lock (_lock) list_clients.Remove(id);
        client.Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        client.Close();
    }
```

and this is my Client:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(Dns.GetHostAddresses("hostname.net").FirstOrDefault(), 5000);
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        client.Connect(ipep);
        Console.WriteLine("Connected to the server");
        NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
        Thread thread = new Thread(o => ReceiveData((TcpClient)o));

        thread.Start(client);

        string s;
        while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((s = Console.ReadLine())))
        {
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
            ns.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

        client.Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);
        thread.Join();
        ns.Close();
        client.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Disconnected");            
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

The problem is that the client connects to the server, but the server doesn't find the client connected, even if I close the server, the client remains connected. This issue started to happen when I switched from localhost to a no-ip host to make the chat "public".

Where am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It appears that it is the host itself that accepts the connection, rather than forwarding it to your server application. Try changing the port that your app uses, and if that doesn't work contact the support/administrators of the host.

Comment: Could you share your code for `ReceiveData`?